# ActiveDirectory Authentication using NODE for Windows SQL 2012

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, node-modules

Am using node Active directory for validating users. Here is my node code:

```
const express = require('express');    
const async = require('async');
const activedirectory = require('activedirectory');
var underscore = require('underscore');
const ldap = require('ldapjs');
const bunyan = require('bunyan');

const app = express();

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
var config = { url: 'ldap://10.100.1.10',
               baseDN: 'dc=HBCAudit,dc=COM',
               username: 'traveldesk.dev',
               password: '$oftvision@123' }
var ad = new activedirectory(config);
});

//Port Number
const port = 7000;

//CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

//Start Server
app.listen(port, () =>{
console.log('Server started on port '+ port);
});
```

But am getting error in command prompt like this:

```
c:\spitravel>node app.js
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'once'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\spitravel\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js
:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I don't know why am getting this error. Am new to NODEJS.

Comment: seems like you have problem with installed packages, https://www.npmjs.com/package/once . if you have package.json containing packages list, you should "npm install" or check for dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Its due to depencies of ldapjs module, please run `npm install ldapjs` and recheck

Comment: Actually I had problem with node version. Now I used the latest version working fine. Thanks for support.